# How to layer text over column widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

edit:[image]
I made "I AM" bright neon green, but its mixing with the button colors to a dark green.

I want to display text over two buttons that cover the whole screen, 1 top half and 1 bottom half. I want text to display in the middle of the screen, kind of covering part of each button.
This is my code for the buttons:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.black87,
            child: poorText,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.black87,
            child: richText,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdRoute()),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);}
```

I have tried to use stack, but it says too many positional arguments are being used. How would I keep my column layout and layer text over the buttons? If there is another way without column that still allows makes the buttons work that's fine too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Stack` widget to achieve that:

Note. Because the two buttons are aligned to the center, you have to align the text widget also to the center so it can be placed directly ob=ver the two button.

Check the code below:
It works perfectly:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    // use a stack widget
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        // text to display over buttons
        Align(
          // set alignment to center to place it over the buttons
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            'Text you want to display over the buttons',
            // give it your style
            style: TextStyle(

            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  child: poorText,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  child: richText,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdRoute()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It works, but for some reason the color from the buttons in the back messes with the color of the text. Is there some way to override that? It looks like the colors are mixing.

Comment: Post a screenshot of  and let me see how I will be able to fix that properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 `Columns` widget within a `Stack` widget. The code below achieves exactly what you want if I understood you well.

```html
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdRoute()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              // set alignment to center to place it over the buttons
              height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

              child: Center(child: Text('Text 1')),
            ),
            Container(
              // set alignment to center to place it over the buttons
              height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

              child: Center(child: Text('Text 2')),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```